# How to make a simple firefox addon, which just executes stand-alone JS script on every new page?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm trying to make a simple firefox add-on, executing a simple stand-alone JS-script on every new page (say, just a simple alert after page loaded).

First, I've tried add-on sdk. It have been installed successfully, run tests, but was not able to execute even examples from any tutorial, so i tried to try XUL.

I downloaded 'xulschoolhello.xpi', unpacked it, modified **content/browserOverlay.xul** to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    

<!DOCTYPE overlay SYSTEM
  "chrome://xulschoolhello/locale/browserOverlay.dtd">

<overlay id="xulschoolhello-browser-overlay"
  xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

  <script type="application/x-javascript"
    src="chrome://xulschoolhello/content/browserOverlay.js" />
</overlay>
```

and **content/browserOverlay.js** to this just to see if something happens:

```
window.alert(123)
```

but nothing happens after zip packing, installation and rebooting.

I'm quiet new to firefox extensions, so thanks for any help.

---

UPD.

I tried to make a very simple **bootstrap.js**:

```
var WindowListener = {
    onOpenWindow: function(window) {
        window.alert(123)
    }
}

function startup(data, reason) {
    var wm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);

    wm.addListener(WindowListener);
}

function shutdown(data, reason) {}
function install(data, reason) {}
function uninstall(data, reason) {}
```

But it doestn alert. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This is a fully working bootstap addon that runs javascript everytime a url matching `hostPatern` of `bing.com` is loaded. Download the xpi from this gist here and install it to see it working:
https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9287185

If you want to use this for yourself, then just edit the `addDiv` and `removeDiv` functions on the js you want to run. And to control which site edit `hostPattern` global var and decide if you want to listen to frames by setting global var of `ignoreFrames`.

To accomplish this with addon-sdk you do it like this:

```
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
const data = require("self").data;


exports.main = function() {
  pageMod.PageMod({ 
    include: ["https://www.bing.com/*","http://www.google.com/*"],
    contentScriptWhen: 'ready',
    /*contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery.js"),data.url("script.js")],*/
    onAttach: function(worker) {
       console.log('loaded a page of interest');
    }
});
```

I'm not too familiar with addon-sdk like i dont know how to set up the environment, but i heard once you get it setup its pretty simple. As you can see by comparing the amount of code. But in the bootstrap version you have fine control over everything thats why I prefer bootstrap, and most of the codes are cookie-cutter copy and paste.

Comment: Thanks. I tried simple bootstrap code (at question update), but didnt succeed :(

Comment: What are you trying to do? Ill write it for you and give to you. Its a 10min edit to that file there.

Comment: I appreciate that, but i dont need 95% of this code, i need just one alert and to understand how it works

Comment: if you want to use bootstrap.js then this is the code you need. if you want to use add-sdk then this is not the code you need. if you want to see an alert on bing.com go to `addDiv` function and add into that function `theDoc.defaultView.alert('hello you landed on a bing.com page')`

Comment: Yes, I've done this. But I want to understand the code, so i tried to cut off all unneeded stuff and to make it just alert at every new window. What i'm doing wrong at the example, or if everything is wrong, how should i do this?

Comment: Oh just new firefox browser (xul) window?

Comment: Just signal alert in every new window :)